# How to match a value to a string within "rules" using jquery validate.js (bassistance.de)

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I want to check if a form radio input value matches a string exactly, something like "equalTo" but just to match a string and not another field input but can't find if there is a simple way to do this similar to using "equalTo".

As below I want the form field "foo" value to match "bar" exactly and was hoping to replace the ????????s with a simple command if this is possible?

If not I would really appreciate some help showing how I can implement a string match within the "rules" method.

```
$("#this_form").validate({
rules:{
            name:{
                 required:true
                 },
             foo:{
                 ????????: "bar",
                 required:true
                 }
        }
```

});

So here I want the form to only validate if the value of foo is "bar" and not if the value is "manchu".

< input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" />

< input type="radio" name="foo" value="manchu" />

(I think the reason is pretty obvious, the answer to foo needs to be bar otherwise I do not want the form to submit.)

Comment: I have a purpose, the question is about the method not the purpose.

Comment: it wasn't a snide comment :) if we know what you are trying to achieve there may be some other way of getting there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("myFunc", function(val) {
    if(val=='myString'){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, "Values do not match.");
```

You can then use this method 'myFunc' like you would use the built in email function.

```
...
foo:{
     myFunc:true
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Eddie truly appreciated but this doesn't seem to work. I have tried the function with val=='bar', the function works fine but will not validate even when the radio button with the correct value is selected. I can get this to work fine with a text field. I may be missing something fundamental here but its almost like the validator does not recognise the value of radio buttons?

Comment: You could probably extend this to rather use `myFunc : 'thevalue'` as the rule and then update the method to use the parameter as the value required.